# SyncBackPro command line hanging

Tags: syncback

I am trying to create a sync back pro profile that I can execute remotely via the command line.

The profile runs correctly when used through the application UI and on the machines local command line, but when I try and execute it remotely via psexec and the command line, it just hangs.  No response is given, it never ends the run, it never presents any prompts including a UAC prompt.

The sync back pro documentation on their website is limited when it comes to the command line.  But as near as I can tell it is simply:

```
SyncBackPro "Profile Name With Spaces In Quotes"
```

I know there isn't much to go on here, but does anyone have any ideas why it is not working for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a hunch, I tried running SyncBackPro with the non-elevated method as described here:
https://help.2brightsparks.com/support/solutions/articles/43000335833?_ga=2.55749292.684918794.1624484488-1607077111.1624484488

> Creating a non-elevated copy
>
> As an Administrator, open Windows File Explorer and navigate In the
> folder SyncBackSE is installed to:
>
> - Close SyncBackSE
> - Copy SyncBackSE.exe to SyncBackSE2.exe
> - Copy SyncBackSE.exe.manifest.nonadmin to SyncBackSE2.exe.manifest

That turned out to be half the equation.  The other half was making sure to have psexec run the file under the users account who created the profile in SyncBackPro.  SyncBackPro creates profiles that are specific to a computer user account, and I have not yet figured out how to make them available across user accounts.